# Update with concat in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to add a string to the existing datas in database, so for that i use normaly "concat"

My trie to do it with codeigniter failed

```
$daten['mycolumn1']='my new content';
$daten['mycolumn2']='my new content';
$daten['mycolumn3']="CONCAT('".date('U').";".$myvar.";mytext'),'mydbtable.mycolumn')";
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

This also wont work

```
$daten['mycloumn3']=CONCAT("'".date('U').";".$myvar.";mytext','mydbtable.mycolumn'");
```

This statement add the complete "CONCAT('".date('U').";".$myvar.";mytext'),'mydbtable.mycolumn')" text to the "mycolumn"

What i do wrong?

Comment: too many ')' bracket,
should be `"CONCAT('".date('U').";".$myvar.";mytext','mydbtable.mycolumn')"`

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'U' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: @LbG this also only update the complete content of mycolumns with this text "CONCAT('1590484706;31;mytext','mydbtable.mycolumn'.."

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find a way to do it in one statement, so i split the job in two steps

```
//For all other datas
$this->db->set($data);

//For the concat statement
$this->db->set('mycloumn', 'CONCAT(mycloumn,\''.date('U').';'.$myvar.';mytext#\')', FALSE);
```